# Fillna row wise as per change in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in which there is a column containing several NaN values. The dataframe looks like this:

```
            col_1   col_2
2022-10-31  99.094  102.498
2022-11-30  99.001  101.880
2022-12-31     NaN  108.498
2023-01-31     NaN  100.500
```

I want to fill those NaN based on the simple calculation below:

```
desired_val = (current value in col_2 - previous value in col_2) + previous value in col_1
```

which means,

`df.loc['2022-12-31', 'col_1']` should be = (108.498 - 101.880) + 99.001 = 105.619

and `df.loc['2023-01-31', 'col_1']` should be = (100.500 - 108.498) + 105.619 = 97.621

I found solution by using row by row operation but it is slow when the dataset is big.

```
for row in df.columns:
        if df.loc[row, 'col_1'] == np.Nan:
            df.loc[row, 'col_1'] = (
              (df['col_2']-df['col_2'].shift(1)
              )
              + df['col_1'].shift(1)
              ).loc[row, 'col_1']
```

Is there any column wise pandas solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to cumulate differences in `col_2` and use those to calculate `col_1` based on the last available value:

```
df["col_1"] = df["col_1"].fillna(df["col_2"].diff().where(df["col_1"].isna()).cumsum()+df["col_1"].ffill())

>>> df
              col_1    col_2
2022-10-31   99.094  102.498
2022-11-30   99.001  101.880
2022-12-31  105.619  108.498
2023-01-31   97.621  100.500
```